# After upgrade TYPO3 to 6.2 extended tab in tt_news extension disappeed

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, tt-news, pibase

In the past I created small extension to extend the tt_news possibility. By kickstarter I have created two new fields to tt_news table. Everything worked fine - on every tt_news record I have two flexform fields in "extended" tab.

After upgrade to TYPO3 6.2 these field disappeared. Is there any chance to turn them on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **typo3conf/PackageStates.php** file make sure that **yourextname** mentioned by **Vishal** is placed under the **tt_news** (just be sure that  your ext is loaded *after* tt_news) otherwise the last one will *cover* your changes.

Answer (score 1):

I did not get your question completely but i think your are looking For this. Please Go to **typo3conf/PackageStates.php** which is located parallel to ext folder.

```
'yourextname' => 
array (
  'composerName' => 'typo3conf/ext/yourextname',
  'state' => 'active',
  'packagePath' => 'typo3conf/ext/yourextname',
  'classesPath' => 'Classes/',

),
```

Change the **State** From **inactive** to **active**. Hopes you are looking for same.